# FileNotFoundException when clicking on button to upload audio

Tags: java, android, soundcloud, filenotfoundexception, android-mediarecorder

I am uploading audio on soundcloud server but when i click upload button it throws FileNotFoundException.After uploading a response from server has to be generated.plss help me guys. please correct me if i am making mistake somewhere.

There are 2 situation in which upload function is performed.
1.Recording of only one page story audio and uloding it.(in this case the audio is being uploade).
2. Recording of more than one page story in which after uploading of 1st page audio the 2nd page will come as response from my server.(In this case its throwing FileNotFound Exception).

```
        upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String tag_string_req = "req_login";
                StringRequest postStringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, SC_LOGIN_LINK,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {

                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                Log.d(TAG,"Reponse Check for sound upload login :"+response);

                                // Log.d(TAG,"Object Check :"+json);
                                try {
                                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                                    access_token = json.getString("access_token");
                                    expires_in = json.getString("expires_in");
                                    refresh_token = json.getString("refresh_token");
//                                doFileUpload();
                                    new AsyncTaskRunner().execute();
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                //Toast.makeText(AccessToken.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                Log.e(TAG, "Error Response Check :" + error);

                            }
                        }){

                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put("client_id", client_id);
                        params.put("client_secret",client_secret);
                        params.put("grant_type",grant_type);
                        params.put("username",username);
                        params.put("password",user_password);
                        Log.d(TAG, "Params :" + params);
                        return params;

                    }


                };                    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(postStringRequest, tag_string_req);
            }
        });

    }
    private void mergeAudioFiles(){
        try {
            File tempFolder = new File(mRawAudioFolder.getPath());
            Movie[] movies = new Movie[tempFolder.listFiles().length];
            int i = 0;
            for (File saveTempFile : tempFolder.listFiles()) {
                try {
                    movies[i] = MovieCreator.build(new FileDataSourceImpl(saveTempFile));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                i++;
            }

            final Movie finalMovie = new Movie();

            List<Track> audioTracks = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Movie movie : movies) {
                for (Track track : movie.getTracks()) {
                }
            }
            finalMovie.addTrack(new AppendTrack(audioTracks.toArray(new Track[audioTracks.size()])));
            final Container container = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(finalMovie);
            mergedFile = new File(mAudioFolder.getPath()+"/merged.3gp");
            final FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(mergedFile);
            FileChannel fc = new RandomAccessFile(mergedFile, "rw").getChannel();
            container.writeContainer(fc);
            fc.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void createAudioFolder() {
        File movieFile = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES);
        mRawAudioFolder = new File(movieFile, "Temp");
        mAudioFolder = new File(movieFile, "The Tagore Project");
        if (!mAudioFolder.exists()) {
            mAudioFolder.mkdirs();
        }
        if (!mRawAudioFolder.exists()) {
            mRawAudioFolder.mkdirs();
        }
    }
    public byte[] toByteArray(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int read = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (read != -1) {
            read = in.read(buffer);
            if (read != -1)
                out.write(buffer,0,read);
        }
        out.close();
        return out.toByteArray();
    }

    public void forwardtoOurServer() {

        String tag_string_req = "req_login";
        StringRequest postStringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, RECORD_COMPOSITION_API,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Audio Upload Response Check :" + response);

                        Log.d(TAG,"Object Check :"+response);
                        try {
                            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                            String code = json.getString("code");
                            if (String.valueOf(code).equals("200")) {

                                JSONObject upload = json.getJSONObject("upload");
                                JSONObject Booking = json.getJSONObject("upload").getJSONObject("Booking");
                                JSONObject Composition = json.getJSONObject("upload").getJSONObject("Composition");
                                JSONObject TableofContents = json.getJSONObject("upload").getJSONObject("TableOfContent");
                                String content = Composition.getString("content");
                                String pageno = Composition.getString("pageno");
                                String tocid = Composition.getString("table_of_content_id");
                                String wrd_count = Composition.getString("wordcount");
                                String tocName = TableofContents.getString("name");

                            } else {
                                String errorMsg = json.getString("error_msg");
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error Response Check :" + error);

                    }
                }) {

            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("data[Booking][id]",bookingId);
                params.put("data[Booking][contributor_id]",contributor_id);
                params.put("data[Booking][table_of_content_id]",tocId);
                params.put("data[Booking][cdn_id]",vs_cdn_id);
                params.put("data[Booking][secret_token]",secret_token);
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
                sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
                Date now = new Date();
                String strDate = sdf.format(now);
                params.put("data[Booking][uploaded_on]",strDate);
                Log.d(TAG, "Params :" + params);
                return params;
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                headers.put("UUID", device_uuid);
                headers.put("APPID", "2A192A0C22");
                headers.put("USERID", "1");
                headers.put("PLATFORM", "Andriod");
                headers.put("APP_REQUEST", "1");
                headers.put("PLATFORMVERSION",androidOS);
                return headers;
            }

        };


        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(postStringRequest, tag_string_req);

    }
    public void MediaRecorderReady(){
        mediaRecorder=new MediaRecorder();
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(AudioSavePathInDevice);
    }

    public String CreateRandomAudioFileName(int string){
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder( string );
        int i = 0 ;
        while(i < string ) {
            stringBuilder.append(RandomAudioFileName.
                    charAt(random.nextInt(RandomAudioFileName.length())));

            i++ ;
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    private void requestPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(RecordComposition.this, new
                String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, RECORD_AUDIO}, RequestPermissionCode);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RequestPermissionCode:
                if (grantResults.length> 0) {
                    boolean StoragePermission = grantResults[0] ==
                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean RecordPermission = grantResults[1] ==
                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

                    if (StoragePermission && RecordPermission) {
                        Toast.makeText(RecordComposition.this, "Permission Granted",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(RecordComposition.this,"Permission Denied",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    public boolean checkPermission() {
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int result1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                RECORD_AUDIO);
        return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                result1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }
    private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            doFileUpload();
            return null;
        }
    }
    private void doFileUpload(){
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        //DataOutputStream dos = null;
        //DataInputStream inStream = null;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary =  "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;
        String responseFromServer = "";
        String urlString = "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks";
        try
        {
            //------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(mergedFile);
            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            URL url = new URL   (urlString);
            // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            conn.setUseCaches(false);

            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() );
            //Adding oauth token
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"oauth_token\""+lineEnd+lineEnd+access_token+lineEnd);
//            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            //Adding Track title
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"track[title]\""+lineEnd+lineEnd+tocName+"by Contributor"+":"+" "+contributorName+lineEnd);
            //Track taglist
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"track[tag_list]\""+lineEnd+lineEnd+"Tagore Project"+lineEnd);
            //Add sharing
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"track[sharing]\""+lineEnd+lineEnd+"private"+lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"track[asset_data]\";filename=\"" + mergedFile + "\"" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Type: audio/mpeg"+lineEnd+lineEnd);
            // create a buffer of maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd+twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
            Log.e("Debug","File is written - "+mergedFile+" - "+conn.getResponseCode());
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException ex)
        {
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
            Toast.makeText(this, ioe.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader inStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String str;
            Log.e("Debug","Before while");
            while (( str = inStream.readLine()  ) != null)
            {
                Log.e("Debug","Server Response "+str);
                JSONObject response = new JSONObject(str);
                vs_cdn_id = response.getString("id");
                secret_token = response.getString("secret_token");
                forwardtoOurServer();
            }
            inStream.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ioex){
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Log:

```
File is written - /storage/emulated/0/Movies/The Tagore Project/merged.3gp - 500
      error: https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks
                                                                                  java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks
                                                                                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:238)
                                                                                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
                                                                                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
                                                                                      at com.showhow2.www.thetagoreproject.RecordComposition.doFileUpload(RecordComposition.java:923)
                                                                                      at com.showhow2.www.thetagoreproject.RecordComposition.access$2400(RecordComposition.java:73)
                                                                                      at com.showhow2.www.thetagoreproject.RecordComposition$AsyncTaskRunner.doInBackground(RecordComposition.java:829)
                                                                                      at com.showhow2.www.thetagoreproject.RecordComposition$AsyncTaskRunner.doInBackground(RecordComposition.java:824)
                                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: It means the file doesn't exist.  Why not post the stack trace so we can help more?

Comment: posted the satcktrace

Comment: please see the edited question

Answer (score 0):

Add this on your code in your Activity class

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> types = new ArrayList<>();

    //add item to manes and types array

    ListViewAdapter customList = new ListViewAdapter(this, names, types);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    list.setAdapter(customList);
}
```

This is ListViewAdapter class

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private ArrayList<String> names;
ArrayList<Integer> types;
private Activity context;

public ListViewAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<String> names, ArrayList<Integer> types) {
    super(context, R.layout.item_rating_rows, names);
    this.context = context;
    this.names = names;
    this.types = types;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_rating_rows, null, true);

    Button btn = (Button) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.btn);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("__onclick", "" + view.getId());
        }
    });

    return listViewItem;
}
```

}

Comment: where should i add this

Comment: did you use ListViewAdapter for add item to listview

Comment: no,not in this activity,but i used ListViewAdapter in some previous activity.

Comment: but i am not using listview adapter in this class.

Comment: Its not the issue of listview  adapter ,Its the issue of FileNotFoundException on Buffer Reader. Is anyone here to help me out??

Answer (score 0):

Give permission in menifest...

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```